# Pdf generating don't work in Laravel proj

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm having trouble displaying PDF files in an inline frame on my website. I am using the pdfmake library to generate the PDF and an inline frame to display the result.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
  
@section('title', '')
  
@section('contents')
<style>
     .country-card {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
        background-color: #3498db;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .country-card img {
        width: 20px;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .country-card span {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 30px; /* Збільште це значення відповідно до вашого вигляду */
    }

    .country-card:hover {
        background-color: #2980b9;
    }
    .country-block {
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
             margin-bottom: 20px;
             padding: 10px;
             background-color: #f8f9fa;
         }
 
         /* Оформлення для кнопок країн */
         .country-btn {
             background-color: #007bff;
             color: #fff;
             border: none;
             padding: 10px;
             cursor: pointer;
             margin-right: 10px;
         }
 
         /* Оформлення для блоку компаній */
         .company-cards {
             display: flex;
             flex-wrap: wrap;
             gap: 10px;
             margin-top: 10px;
         }
 
         /* Оформлення для блоку компанії */
         .company-card {
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
             padding: 10px;
             background-color: #fff;
             line-height: 1.2; /* Зменшення інтервалу між текстовими елементами */
             overflow: hidden; /* Заборона виділення за межі блоку */
             margin-right: 10px;
         }
 
         /* Оформлення для блоку вакансій */
         .vacancy-cards {
             display: flex;
             flex-wrap: wrap;
             gap: 10px;
             margin-top: 10px;
         }
 
         /* Оформлення для блоку вакансії */
         
 </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <h1 class="mb-0">Проекти</h1>
        <a href="{{ route('project.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Додати проект</a>
    </div>
    <hr />
    @if(Session::has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ Session::get('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    
    
    <div class="country-card" data-country="Угорщина">
        <img src="{{ asset('admin_assets/img/hungary.png') }}" alt="Угорщина Прапор">
        <span>Угорщина</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="country-card" data-country="Словаччина">
        <img src="{{ asset('admin_assets/img/slovakia.png') }}" alt="Словаччина Прапор">
        <span>Словаччина</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="country-card" data-country="Чехія">
        <img src="{{ asset('admin_assets/img/czech-republic.png') }}" alt="Чехія Прапор">
        <span>Чехія</span>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    
    
    @php
        $uniqueCountries = $project->pluck('country')->unique();
    @endphp
    
    @foreach($uniqueCountries as $country)
        <div class="country-block" id="{{ $country }}">
            <h2>{{ $country }}</h2>
            <div class="company-cards">
                @php
                    $uniqueCompanies = $project->where('country', $country)->pluck('company')->unique();
                @endphp
    
                @foreach($uniqueCompanies as $companyIndex => $company)
                    <div class="card company-card" data-country="{{ $country }}" data-company="{{ $company }}">
                        <!-- Ваш код для компаній -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $company }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ $project->where('country', $country)->where('company', $company)->first()->city }}</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary details-btn" data-index="{{ $companyIndex }}">Детальніше</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
                <hr>
            <div class="vacancy-cards" id="{{ $country }}" style="display: none;">
                @foreach($uniqueCompanies as $companyIndex => $company)
                    @php
                        $vacancies = $project->where('country', $country)->where('company', $company);
                    @endphp
    
                    @foreach($vacancies as $vacancyIndex => $vacancy)
                        <div class="card vacancy-card" style="margin: 10px; display: none;" data-index="{{ $companyIndex }}">
                            <!-- Ваш код для вакансій -->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $vacancy->vacancy }}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ $vacancy->job }}</p> 
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openPDFEditor('{{ $vacancy->id }}')">Створити PDF</button>

                                <div id="pdfEditorModal_{{ $vacancy->id }}" style="display: none; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); z-index: 9999; ">
                                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                                        <h3>Редактор PDF</h3>
                                        <button type="button" onclick="closePDFEditor('{{ $vacancy->id }}')">✖</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div style="display: flex;" >
                                        <div id="pdfPreview" style="margin-right: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;  "></div>
                                        <div>
                                            <label for="name">Країна</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="name" required>
                                            <br>
                                            <label for="email">Назва проекту\заводу</label>
                                            <input type="email" id="email" required>
                                            <br>
                                            <button type="button" onclick="generateAndPreviewPDF()">Створити і Переглянути PDF</button>
                                            <br> <br>
                                            <button type="button" onclick="downloadPDF()">Завантажити PDF</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Ховаємо всі блоки крім блоків країн
            $('.country-block, .company-cards, .vacancy-card, .details-btn').hide();
    
            $(document).on('click', '.country-card', function(){
                var countryId = $(this).data('country');
    
                // Ховаємо всі блоки крім блоків компаній в обраній країні
                $('.country-block').hide();
                $('#'+countryId).show();
    
                // Ховаємо всі блоки крім блоків компаній
                $('.company-cards').hide();
    
                // Показуємо блок компаній в обраній країні
                $('#'+countryId+' .company-cards').show();
    
                // Ховаємо всі блоки вакансій та кнопок "Детальніше"
                $('.details-btn').show();
            });
    
            $(document).on('click', '.details-btn', function(){
                var index = $(this).data('index');
    
                // Ховаємо всі блоки вакансій
                $('.vacancy-card').hide();
    
                // Показуємо вакансії для обраної компанії
                $('.vacancy-card[data-index="'+index+'"]').show();
            }); 
        });
        
   
        function openPDFEditor(vacancyId) {
    document.getElementById('pdfEditorModal_' + vacancyId).style.display = 'block';
}

function closePDFEditor(vacancyId) {
    document.getElementById('pdfEditorModal_' + vacancyId).style.display = 'none';
}


function generateAndPreviewPDF() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

            // Створення документу pdfmake
            var docDefinition = {
    pageOrientation: 'portrait',
    pageSize: 'A4',
    pageMargins: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    content: [
        {
            canvas: [
                { type: 'rect', x: 0, y: 0, w: 595.28, h: 841.89, color: '#F9F3E4' }
            ]
        },
        {
            absolutePosition: { x: 10, y: 20 },
            columns: [
                {
                    width: 'auto',
                    text: 'flag1',
                    alignment: 'left'
                },
                {
                    width: '*',
                    text: 'ALEXXQUALITYWORK',
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: 'blue',
                    alignment: 'center'
                },
                {
                    width: 'auto',
                    text: 'flag2',
                    alignment: 'right'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            absolutePosition: { x: 10, y: 40 },
            canvas: [
                { type: 'line', x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 575.28, y2: 0, lineWidth: 2, lineColor: 'gold' }
            ]
        },
        {
            absolutePosition: { x: 10, y: 60 },
            text: 'НАЗВА КРАЇНИ - НАЗВА КОМПАНІЇ',
            fontSize: 14,
            alignment: 'center',
            bold: true
        },
        {
            absolutePosition: { x: 10, y: 80 },
            canvas: [
                { type: 'line', x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 575.28, y2: 0, lineWidth: 2, lineColor: 'gold' }
            ]
        },
        {
            absolutePosition: { x: 10, y: 100 },
            ul: [
                `${name} (Місце роботи)`,
                `${email} (Назва професії)`,
                'Обмеження щодо статі та віку',
                {
                    text: 'Короткі відомості',
                    ul: [
                        'Наявність змін на виробництві',
                        'Кількість робочих годин',
                        'Заробітна плата'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: 'Умови проживання',
                    ul: [
                        'Умова 1',
                        'Умова 2',
                        'Умова 3'
                    ]
                }
            ],
            fontSize: 12
        },
        {
            absolutePosition: { x: 10, y: 200 },
            text: 'ALEXXQUALITYWORK'
        }
    ]
};


            // Створення PDF документу і отримання Blob
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBlob((blob) => {
                // Відображення PDF у вбудованому фреймі
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var pdfViewer = document.getElementById('pdfPreview');
                pdfViewer.innerHTML = `<iframe width="500" height="500" src="${url}" frameborder="0"></iframe>`;
            });
        }

        function downloadPDF() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

            // Створення документу pdfmake
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [
                    { text: 'Мій PDF Заголовок', fontSize: 18, color: 'blue' },
                    { text: `Ім'я: ${name}`, fontSize: 12 },
                    { text: `Електронна пошта: ${email}`, fontSize: 12 },
                    { text: 'Мій PDF Підпис', fontSize: 14, color: 'black' }
                ]
            };

            // Створення PDF документу і вивантаження
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('my_pdf');
        }
    
</script>



@endsection
```

The problem is that the PDF is not displayed in the inline frame. Can anyone provide any advice or guidance on how to resolve this issue?
I've trying a lot, but nothing helps....
Also I've tried ChatGPT....

Comment: Is it generating the PDF at all, or just not generating it in the right place? If you check the developer tab, does it give you any information there? It's being created with Javascript, so unless there's an issue with the generated HTML or javascript, Laravel and PHP aren't really involved here.

Comment: What is the content of the inline frame? Shouldn't be that hard to find out what it is displaying? What do the laravel logs say?

Comment: @aynber
It is not generating PDFs at all. and it not providing any info in the dev tab
btw I haven't made any changes to PDF function
I really need that shit ASAP
I can pay for that if needed...

Comment: @dbf it needs to be a preview
but laravel log says nothing...